# Cakephp could not create tmp folder

Tags: php, cakephp, permissions, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm using vagrant to setup my centos 6.6 x86_64 virtual OS. I have installed apache and cakephp into it.

I have let Apache run as vagrant user and in vagrant group. And the vagrant's `Vagrantfile` has the line `config.vm.synced_folder "./gym", "/var/www", mount_options: ["dmode=777", "fmode=777"]`.

After I run the index.php, the cakephp report the error:

> PHP Warning:  /var/www/gym_new/app/tmp/cache/persistent/ is not writable in /var/www/cake_2_6/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php on line 385
>
> PHP Warning:  _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'file_map' to File cache in /var/www/cake_2_6/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 328

So I open the `FileEngine.php` there is the code trigger error:

```
/**
 * Determine is cache directory is writable
 *
 * @return bool
 */
    protected function _active() {
        $dir = new SplFileInfo($this->settings['path']);
        if (Configure::read('debug')) {
            $path = $dir->getPathname();
            if (!is_dir($path)) {
                mkdir($path, 0775, true);
            }
        }
        if ($this->_init && !($dir->isDir() && $dir->isWritable())) {
            $this->_init = false;
            trigger_error(__d('cake_dev', '%s is not writable', $this->settings['path']), E_USER_WARNING);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I think the permission has no problem so I create a brand new php just under webroot:

```
$path = "/var/www/gym_new/app/tmp/cache/";
if(mkdir($path, 0775, true) && is_dir($path) && is_writable($path))
{
    echo "true";
}
else
{
    echo "false";
    $error = error_get_last();
    echo $error['message'];
}
```

My code runs perfect and the folders (tmp and cache) is created successful. But the same code in cakephp cannot go through. So is there anything I have missed? **The cakephp file is outside of the webroot**, dose this cause the problem ?

Comment: Please write an answer and accept it, don't edit your question to say "solved"

Comment: @AD7six I'm shy of accept my own answer, I will write it down.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `if (Configure::read('debug'))`.

I found I haven't set debug to non-zero value, so cakephp won't create the folders even they don't exist.

Comment: Why the debug must be enabled? How about production server?

Comment: I don't know, maybe a bug? I do not use cakephp for a long time.

Comment: What do you use now?

Comment: @neobie I switch to C++ and C# now.